# jQuery Keydown/Keyup only works every second time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have keyup/down events binded to the document. The Keydown will only fires every second time, without me knowing why. I tried many suggestions given on similar SO-Questions, but none of them works.

My Javascript:

```
$(document).on('keyup', function() {
    $('div').removeClass('bar');
});
$(document).on('keydown', function(e) {
    if(e.altKey) {
        $('div').addClass('bar');  // only every second hit will add the class
    }
});
```

This should point out the issue:
http://jsfiddle.net/6yxt53m9/1/

Comment: Do you have to use the alt key?

Comment: Works the first time for me under ubuntu and chrome

Comment: Yes it must be the alt key

Comment: I'm on Chrome at Mac, but this fiddle is working fin for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use

```
$(document).on('keyup', function(e) {
    $('div').removeClass('bar');
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

e.preventDefault(); will reset the input

Comment: Mark the answer as accepted but looking at http://jsfiddle.net/6yxt53m9/8/ not sure if it fixes the problem, I might be missing something though.

Answer (score 7):

You need to add `return false;` to the key press functions:

```
$(document).on('keyup', function() {
    $('div').removeClass('bar');
    return false;
});

$(document).on('keydown', function(e) {
    if(e.altKey) {
        $('div').addClass('bar');
    }
    return false;
});
```

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6yxt53m9/6/).

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
$(document).on('keydown', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if(e.altKey) {
        $('div').addClass('bar');  // only every second hit will add the class
    }
});
```

The reason is alt key occurs focus moving to button of "customize and control google chorome"
[image]